# Javascript redirect not working with URL's starting with www

Tags: javascript

I tried to redirect to `www.google.com` like this:

```
    window.location.replace('www.google.com');
```

However, it does not work. But If I use `http` or `https` then it works:

```
    window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
```

But since not every site supports **https** I always have to insert `http` to make sure the redirect works for sure.

Comment: yes, but if it does support `https` - it will redirect to `https`

Comment: Try //www.google.com

Comment: Every webserver that supports https should support http and redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use urls without protocol:

```
 window.location.replace('//www.google.com');
```